# How to export inner members of an existing Typescript declarations module

Tags: typescript

Let's say that I have a declarations file describing the shape of a node module that exports an object with multiple members. This file exists at `foo/index.d.ts` and looks like:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: () => void;
  // ... more members here
}


declare var Foo: Foo;
export = Foo;
```

With this, I can require and use the module as normal when compiling:

```
import * as Foo from 'foo';
Foo.bar();
```

However, I now want to also be able to do this:

```
import * as bar from 'foo/bar';
bar();
```

I've tried every possible combination of declaration file paths, modules, namespaces, and contexts, but I can't get this working. The most obvious, intuitive way would be to create a file at `foo/bar/index.d.ts` with:

```
import * as Foo from '..';
export = Foo.bar;
```

But doing this results in the error: `'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.`

How can I create declaration files that define modules that export both outer and inner members?

**Edit**: Tried to use `declare module` as suggested by @cevek, but this throws the error "Cannot find namespace Foo":

```
declare module "foo/bar" {
  var bar: Foo.bar;
  export = bar;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just `import {bar} from "foo";`? What you want to achieve looks like a hack.

Comment: Which part? The `export = ` is minimally required, as this is describing a node module that has `module.exports =` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), and is standard way of handling this in TS. If it's something else I'm definitely interesting in doing the least hacky way.

Comment: I mean just using that instead of `import * as bar from 'foo/bar';`.  I don't know if your usecase allows that. Basically I would just use standard ES6 module features, and use module declarations where external typing information is needed (so no `exports=`)

Comment: Ah, right. That's the part that doesn't work for me here. It's described in the documentation, however, so it should be possible. This is pretty standard for other libs as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use module declarations

```
//foo.d.ts
    interface Foo {}
    interface Bar {}

    declare module 'foo' {
        export default Foo
    }

    declare module 'foo/bar'{
        export default Bar
    }
```

And use it from another place

```
import * as Foo from 'foo';
import * as Bar from 'foo/bar';
```

Comment: Doing that now results in "cannot find namespace Foo" (posted as edit)

Comment: @Andrew What version of typescript you use?

Comment: It's version 2.1.3